# How do i move my text?

Tags: html

Here's some very simple HTML code,

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Hotel-In Sign up!</h1>
        <p>First name</p>

        <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20">
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

When I see this webpage, the text first name is onto of the form, however I want it to be on the left of the form, how do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You will probably want to use `label`.

Comment: Your title is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pqtzzt6a/)**

```html
<h1> Hotel-In Sign up!</h1>

<form>
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="name" size="20">
</form>
```